# PHP - What is the real use of base64_encode function

Tags: php, character-encoding, base64

I have been using json_encode, url_encode and many other functions suffixed with encode in php. However, I have never seen real use case or atleast learn from anywhere what base64_encode does. Inspecting its output,I realize that it uses Character set [A_Za-z0-9] to encode data.

```
//sample output

TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlz
IHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2Yg
dGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGlu
dWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo
ZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=
```

So the question is. What does base64_encode aim to solve when we already have a myriad of text encoding functions.

Comment: I've seen it used in payment gateway APIs (BarclayCard SmartPay IIRC) to make a sort of message digest of the transaction (combined with a secret key) which you then POST to them using cURL.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) gives you the answer:

> This encoding is designed to make binary data survive transport
>   through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean, such as mail
>   bodies.

`json_encode` converts values into JSON notation and `urlencode` is used when you need to put values inside an URL. Only because they all have the word *encode* in their names doesn't mean that they are related in any way.